# how to get multiple select values

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I want to get list of items in liferay.

I used `<aui:select>` tag like:

```jsp
<aui:select name="select" multiple="true">
    <aui:option value="one"></aui:option>
    <aui:option value="two"></aui:option>
    <aui:option value="three"></aui:option>
    <aui:option value="four"></aui:option>
</aui:select>
```

when the form submitted there is no parameter in ProccessAction.

```java
String[] items =  actionRequest.getParameterValues("select");   
System.out.println(items);
```

How can I submit the **multiple select** items?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code..

```jsp
<aui:select name="select" id="select" multiple="true">
```

```java
String[] items = ParamUtil.getParameterValues(request, "select");

for(String item : items){
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Hope this will help you !!!

Thanks.

Comment: thanks @LuckyBoy. but there is no method ParamUtil.getParameterValues.

Comment: try using in your way..actionRequest.getParameterValues("select");
remember to add "id attribute" in your select

Comment: but there is no parameter named "select";

Comment: when select tag multiple="true" the select not submitted.

Comment: the select is inside form.

Comment: OK...so when your submitting the form your processAction method is called i guess...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22569/discussion-between-habib-zare-and-lucky-boy)

Comment: give me mail id so i can demo portlet

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the name of the parameter in your portlet code. When you use aui taglig remember that it adds always a namespace (like *_yourPortletName_WAR_yourPluginName_*) to your input name. Hence you can change your code like this:

```
String mySelectInputName = actionResponse.getNamespace() + "select";
String[] items =  actionRequest.getParameterValues(mySelectInputName);
```

Alternatives: use the class ParamUtil instead of the direct access to actionRequest.

Hope this help.

Thanks.